# openSSL: Import ECDSA signature from raw data with compressed CurvePoint R instead of r

Tags: c, openssl, ecdsa

I want to verify some data packets which contain an ECDSA signature that is not ASN.1 DER encoded.

I am trying to perform the task with openSSL (version 1.1.0) as it seems to bring all the required functionality.

Currently I am stuck with importing the signature from the data packet.
The signature looks like this:

[image: signature shown in Wireshark]

(The last 4 bytes should not be marked as part of the signature)

TShark shows the relevant part like this:

> ```
>     "gn.sh.sig": {
>       "gn.st.pka": "0",
>       "gn.st.eccpointtype": "3",
>       "gn.st.opaque": "1f:f8:ad:a7:fd:99:b2:a8:a2:69:d4:d6:67:e5:ee:5b:3f:8b:e8:7f:49:fc:b4:79:95:98:15:0d:cb:bd:06:3c",
>       "gn.st.opaque": "61:a4:6a:c9:a7:dd:bd:0d:9c:0a:0e:73:db:52:06:bb:79:53:99:51:16:45:45:81:4e:df:94:5c:58:59:40:14"
>     }
> ```

The encoding is according ETSI TS 103 097 v1.2.1

The first entry `opaque` together with the `ECC Point type` form an EccPoint named `R` while the second field `opaque` is named `s`.

My first step is to create a signature in openSSL and import the data into it.

My code (error handling removed to reduce size) looks like this:

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void verify_signature(void)
{
  int res;

  // Which value is correct for r-part?
  static const char sig_r_hex[] = "1ff8ada7fd99b2a8a269d4d667e5ee5b3f8be87f49fcb4799598150dcbbd063c";
  static const char sig_s_hex[] = "61a46ac9a7ddbd0d9c0a0e73db5206bb79539951164545814edf945c58594014";

  BN_CTX *bn_ctx = BN_CTX_new();
  BN_CTX_start(bn_ctx);

  // Create signature and import from packet.
  BIGNUM *bn_r = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);
  BIGNUM *bn_s = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);

  res = BN_hex2bn(&bn_r, sig_r_hex);
  res = BN_hex2bn(&bn_s, sig_s_hex);

  ECDSA_SIG *signature = ECDSA_SIG_new();
  res = ECDSA_SIG_set0(signature, bn_r, bn_s);
  printf("ECDSA_SIG_set0(): %d\n", res);

  // ...
  // Create hash of message and verify signature with public key
  //...
}

int main(int arc, char *argv[])
{ 
  ERR_load_crypto_strings();
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
  OPENSSL_config(NULL);

  verify_signature();

  EVP_cleanup();
  CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
  ERR_free_strings();
  return 0;
}
```

What I am currently missing is how I should handle the value `R` properly. 
Which parts of the compressed CurvePoint should be used as `r` to initialize the signature?
Do I need to uncompress `y` part?
Do I have to add some indication for the compressed `y` value?

Any hints are welcome.

Edit:

From what I read in IEEE1609.2 and SEC-1 it is possible to add additional information to allow for faster computation of `R` from `r`. This may the the point `R` itself.
As `r = xR mod n` it should be possible to calculate `r` from the EccPoint.

Does openSSL support this mechanism to speed up verification or do I really have to remove the extra information (and find out how to do it) to feed `r` into openSSL?

Answer (score 0):

Sections 4.2.5 -- 4.2.8 in http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/103000_103099/103097/01.02.01_60/ts_103097v010201p.pdf, give the following structures (where `extern` means not literally represented in the data'):

```
enum {
     x_coordinate_only(0),
     compressed_lsb_y_0(2),
     compressed_lsb_y_1(3),
     uncompressed(4),
     (2^8-1)
} EccPointType;

struct {
 extern PublicKeyAlgorithm algorithm;
 extern uint8 field_size;
 EccPointType type;
 opaque x[field_size];
 select(type) {
     case x_coordinate_only:
     case compressed_lsb_y_0:
     case compressed_lsb_y_1:
         ;
     case uncompressed:
         opaque y[field_size];
     unknown:
         opaque data<var>;
     }
} EccPoint;

struct {  
    extern PublicKeyAlgorithm algorithm;  
    extern uint8 field_size;  
    EccPoint R;  
    opaque s[field_size]; 
} EcdsaSignature;

struct {
    PublicKeyAlgorithm algorithm;
    select(algorithm) {
        case ecdsa_nistp256_with_sha256:
            EcdsaSignature ecdsa_signature;
        unknown:
            opaque signature<var>;
    }
} Signature;
```

You know that it's ECDSA on P-256, using SHA256, and that we've got a "compressed y-1" point.  Lets first resolve all of the 'select' portions of these structs using what we know, and eliminate all of the 'extern' fields:

```
struct {
    PublicKeyAlgorithm algorithm; // 1 byte = 0x00 ("ecdsa, P-256, sha256")
    {                             //EcdsaSignature ecdsa_signature
        {                         //EccPoint R
            EccPointType type;        //1 byte = 0x03 ("compressed lsb y-1")
            opaque x[field_size];     //these are the first 32 opaque bytes
            ;                         // select(type) resolves to nothing.
        }  
        opaque s[field_size];     //these are the second 32 opaque bytes
    }
} Signature;
```

Okay. That's simpler.  Now we know what all of the bytes are.  So what's all this business about "compressed points"?  At its heart, point-compression is really about minimizing the amount of data that has to be sent over the network.  It turns out that, given the X coordinate of a point on a NIST curve, you can solve for the Y coordinate, but there are 2 possible answers.  Some clever people at Certicom noticed that the two possible Y coordinates that go with a given X coordinate always differ in their least-significant bit---thus while they have to send all of X, they could get away with only sending the LSb of Y (i.e., just enough info so you know which of the two solutions for Y is correct).  So that EccPointType of "compressed lsb y-1" tells you that for your X coordinate, the correct Y coordinate is the one that has a 1 in the LSb.

The best news about this is that you don't have to care.  ECDSA only uses the X coordinate of R, which is sitting there in the first opaque blob labeled 'x'.

So this was a long-winded explanation to say "you don't have to do anything.  You're already holding the right `r` (= X coord of R) and `s` to feed into OpenSSL's ECDSA_do_verify.